# How to split a spreadsheet into multiple new spreadsheets each containing a subset of the original data?

Tags: excel, vba

My excel spreadsheet contains

```
Name   Grade   Status
Paul   3       M
Paul   3       P
Paul   4       P
Steve  5       O
Steve  5       O
Nick   6       O
 ........
```

I used `freeze panel` and other formatting things .

---

I want to create separate Spreadsheets that would contains only one name. Example:

1. Spreadsheet_paul.xls

   ```
   Name   Grade   Status
   Paul   3       M
   Paul   3       P
   Paul   4       P
   ```
2. Spreadsheet_Nick.xls

   ```
   Name   Grade   Status
   Nick   6       o
   ```

   .........

I need to create separate files, with the number of files at the end equal to the number of names in the original spreadsheet, each containing the corresponding subset of the original data.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can do it with built-in functions, you don't need programming for this. It's a little tough, though.

Comment: Why would people down vote this? It has been an exceptionally useful question and accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code. I've commented it in details. But if you have some quesions, ask in comments:). Code saves new wokrbooks in the folder where your current workbook is saved.

```
Sub test()
    Dim names As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nm As Variant
    Dim res As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
            On Error Resume Next
            'collect unique names
            names.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next cell

        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'change "A1:C1" to headers address of your table
        Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:C1")

        For Each nm In names
            With rngHeader
                'Apply filter to "Name" column
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=nm
                On Error Resume Next
                'get all visible rows 
                Set res = .Offset(2).Resize(lastrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0

                'if there is visible rows, create new WB
                If Not res Is Nothing Then
                    'create new workbook
                    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
                    'add sheet with name form column "Names" ("Paul", "Nick" or etc)
                    wb.Worksheets.Add.name = nm
                    'delete other sheets from new wb
                    For Each ws1 In wb.Worksheets
                        If ws1.name <> nm Then ws1.Delete
                    Next

                    'copy/paste data
                    With wb.Worksheets(nm)
                        'copy headers
                        .Range("A1").Resize(, rngHeader.Columns.Count).Value = rngHeader.Value
                        'copy data
                        .Range("A2").Resize(res.Rows.Count, res.Columns.Count).Value = res.Value
                    End With

                    'save wb
                    wb.Close saveChanges:=True, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Spreadsheet_" & nm & ".xlsx"
                    Set wb = Nothing
                End If
            End With
        Next
        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set names = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This works great. One more question : when we copy paste , is it possible to preserve original formatting ? What can I use instead of  `.Value ` ?

Comment: try to use `rngHeader.Copy .Range("A1")` and `res.copy .Range("A2")` - it will copy everyting including format

Comment: `rngHeader.Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")` and `res.Copy Destination:=.Range("A2")`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have names in cells `A1:A4` in `Data` worksheet, the formula for Paul worksheet will be:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(INDEX(Data!$A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF(Data!$A$1:$A$4="Paul",ROW(Data!$A$1:$A$4),""),ROW(1:1))),0,COLUMN(A:A)-1),"")
```

Mind you, this is an **array** formula, which means that you have to enter it with the combination: Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Now you have to just fill down and to the right to as many cells as you want.

Comment: Thank you +1 . But I specifically need to create separate files . The number of files should equal the number of names