# How to convert VBA into VBScript?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have been looking for a code VBScript that would split an excel workbook into multiple smaller workbooks .

Here on Stackoverflow i encountered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893913/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-out-of-an-existing-spreadsheet) that works perfect . The only problem is that it is a `VBA` and not `VBScript` . I have been trying to convert it myself but was not able to do that . Can anybody help me do that . Here is the `VBA` :

```
Sub test()
    Dim names As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nm As Variant
    Dim res As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'change "A" to column with "Names"
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
            On Error Resume Next
            'collect unique names
            names.Add CStr(cell.Value), CStr(cell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next cell

        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        'change "A1:C1" to headers address of your table
        Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:C1")

        For Each nm In names
            With rngHeader
                'Apply filter to "Name" column
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=nm
                On Error Resume Next
                'get all visible rows 
                Set res = .Offset(2).Resize(lastrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0

                'if there is visible rows, create new WB
                If Not res Is Nothing Then
                    'create new workbook
                    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
                    'add sheet with name form column "Names" ("Paul", "Nick" or etc)
                    wb.Worksheets.Add.name = nm
                    'delete other sheets from new wb
                    For Each ws1 In wb.Worksheets
                        If ws1.name <> nm Then ws1.Delete
                    Next

                    'copy/paste data
                    With wb.Worksheets(nm)
                        'copy headers
                       rngHeader.Copy Destination:=.Range("A1")   
                        'copy data
                       res.Copy Destination:=.Range("A2")
                    End With

                    'save wb
                    wb.Close saveChanges:=True, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Spreadsheet_" & nm & ".xlsx"
                    Set wb = Nothing
                End If
            End With
        Next
        'disable all filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set names = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you study http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info?

Comment: Thank you . i read this . i also read many other tutorials . however , still encounter issues compiling it

Comment: e.g. `  With ws   lastrow = .Cells ` i know that `.Cells ` refers to the `ws` but in VBScript how can I refer to this

Comment: Why is this question getting upvotes? Should just start with a web search, e.g. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Visual+Basic+for+Applications+features+not+in+VBScript

Comment: @CHEBURASHKA start by defining constants as VBScript does not recognize things like `xlUp` nor `xlCelLTypeVisible`. Open VBE and hit F2 to bring up the Object Browser, type in the constants name and you will get their values. You need to declare those constants (*or you their values*) in your VBScript.

Comment: Your answer is completely incomplete. It misses the main point.

Comment: @DavidCandy A comment is a comment is a comment. Not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Should be fixable. Just remember that when you're writing a VBScript program you're no longer *in* Excel. So global objects like `Application` and `ThisWorkbook` are not available. You'll need to create your own objects to reference these. For example:

```
Set Application = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set ThisWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)
```

Now you have the same two objects your VBA code is using in your example. Along the same lines, remembering that you're operating from outside Excel, any constants defined by Excel will be unavailable as well (`xlUp`, `xlCellTypeVisible`, etc.). It is possible to "import" these constants from the Excel type library when using VBScript in a WSF file, however. But it's usually simpler to just lookup the ones you need and define them as `const` yourself.

Aside from that, the rest is just knowing the difference between the VBScript *language* and VBA. For example, you don't declare variables as specific types in VBScript. Also, you can't use `<param>:=<value>` pairs when calling functions in VBScript.

If you follow these suggestions, you should be pretty good shape.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript was designed to be pastable into VB/VBA. As long as you remove the datatypes (use the default varient data type) it mostly works the other way. Because you are running externally you need to connect to excel.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

becomes

```
set excelapp=createobject("Excel.Application")

Set ws = excelapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Payrates.xls").worksheets("Sheet1")

msgbox ws.name
```

Comment: He has to look them up. It gives access to his ws object. Your answer is absolutely useless. Oh, what answer? I gave him the keys to the kingdom. We don't write code here.

Comment: can you explain your statement to me? *`As long as you remove the datatypes (use the default varient data type) it mostly works the other way.`* Why would I have to remove the datatype? What do you mean by that? What about custom data types (*Enums, Type/Struct*). Aren't they compatible between VBScript and VBA?

Comment: @mehow VBScript doesn't support typed variables, so a variable declaration `Dim var As type` must be changed into `Dim var`. However, the answer is still far too incomplete. Plus, I'd like to see a source for the claim that "VBScript was designed to be pastable into VB/VBA".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers oh I know i know (see my profile) I wanted to hear the explanation from David ;)

Comment: If you don't want to study a language you can't be expected to understand it. You'll find it somewhere here, he's the programmer that wrote vbs. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=vbs%20paste%20vb6&beta=0&rn=Fabulous+Adventures+In+Coding&rq=site:blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/&ac=4

Comment: You made the claim. You bring the evidence.

Comment: "VB is to VBScript as Java is to JavaScript." 




Though I can see some truth in that, I'd classify that as a poor analogy. 




Why?  Because VBScript was designed to be a simple subset of the VB language. One of our major design criteria was that a VBScript program be a legal VB program. There are some exceptions, but more or less that's the case. 
From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/08/48762.aspx